# StringGetChar and CharToStr do not interchange

Tags: mql4

I am trying to get a special character (ASCII >127) from a string after I set it there, but the output is changing because CharToStr accepts uchar, and StringGetChar returns ushort.

This is what I've tried:

```
  uchar uch = 234;

  Print(uch);    //Output:  234
  string a = CharToStr(uch);

  uch = (uchar)StringGetChar(a,0);
  Print(uch);    //Output:   218
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: why you may need to get `uchar` back? `CharToStr` is a convenient way to draw so strange objects like wingdings, any idea why you may need to convert it back

Comment: I have a string in the format "[code] go [dir]", where [code] is a wingdings number and [dir] can be "up" or "dn". From this string I want to extract the code and display it in a label in wingdings font, while the rest of the string is displayed in another font.

Comment: If you have a string, you can display it in using one font only. if different fonts - you need to split it to have two strings

Comment: Of course. This was not was I was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest my own answer.
Instead of dealing with `uchar <==> ushort`, which is problematic due to the continous bug in MQL4, you may recode it this way:

```
//let's say it can be any number, unknown in compilation time
string msg = "234My message";
//then somewhere in the code when you want to display the message:
uchar arrow = (uchar)StringToInteger(StringSubstr(msg,0,3));
//and act upon this arrow, now that you have the correct code:
if(arrow==234) { ... }
else if (arrow==233)  { ... }
```